# Removing MorphVox audio drivers from macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, mac, audio, drivers

I installed MorphVox audio changer on my mac for testing, then I uninstalled it, but the audio drivers are still there, I can still see MorphVox speakers and microphone devices. Any tips how can I remove these drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically, you use the uninstaller - see https://screamingbee.com/docs/morphvoxmac/faq

Any app that asks you for Admin perms at install, as opposed to simple drag & drop, will often need a specific uninstaller, available from the app developer.

For anything else, you install something like [App Cleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/), then any time you delete an app it will find all the extra bits that were installed & ask if you also want to delete them.

Comment: Thank you very much